# Default copy behavior with array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor, copy-assignment

If I have a class with an array as a member:

```
class A
{
    Object array[SIZE];
};
```

And I copy an instance of it:

```
A a;
A b = a;
A c;
c = a;
```

will `array` be memcpy-ed byte-by-byte or `Object::operator=` copied element-by-element?

Comment: Perhaps point out that there is only a difference for non-POD types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are well behaved for all first class objects, including user defined types (no matter whether they are POD/non-trivially constructible).

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Object
{
    Object()              { puts("Object");  } 
    Object(Object const&) { puts("copy");    } 
   ~Object()              { puts("~Object"); } 
};

struct A
{
    Object array[4];
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b = a;
}
```

Output (see also http://liveworkspace.org/code/40380f1617699ae6967f0107bf080026):

```
Object
Object
Object
Object
copy
copy
copy
copy
~Object
~Object
~Object
~Object
~Object
~Object
~Object
~Object
```

Comment: The compiler may optimize a POD copy by replacing it with a memcpy or equivalent, but it's not required to.

Comment: I'm not worried about optimizations if they end up with equivalent behavior.  I want to make sure that my container class will behave well with the default copy constructor and assignment operator, regardless of the contained type, before I decide it's O.K. to not implement them myself.

Comment: @John short version: yes you're fine: array elements are also first class objects. This is C++. Even `goto` is safe with constructors/destructors and exceptions etc. You have to try hard to shoot yourself in the foot (but when you do...)